# Skipping spaces in 2d walk grid array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The purpose of this program is to generate a two-dimensional grid array made of periods. The user will designate coordinates on a grid for a "walker" to be placed, marked by 'A'. The walker will choose random cardinal directions to go in, choosing a new one every single time and marking it with the next letter in the alphabet until it reaches 'Z', or until it goes beyond the boundaries. If it reaches a space that it has already been, it checks in the other three directions and moves to the next empty space it finds.

The program runs well for the most part, but usually around the mid-point of the run it will skip ahead several spaces, either leaving a gap with empty space, or appearing to move diagonally (which it should not.)

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DrunkWalker {
    private char[][] walkgrid = new char[10][10];
    private static int randNSEW;
    private static int randNSEWS;
    private int randomnum;
    private int startrow;
    private int startcol;
    private char alpha = 'A';
    private int nextrow;
    private int nextcol;

    public DrunkWalker(int r, int c) {
        startrow = r;
        startcol = c;
        nextrow = startrow;
        nextcol = startcol;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) { 
//Fills walkgrid with periods.
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                walkgrid[i][j] = '.';
        }
        walkgrid[r][c] = alpha++;
    }

    public static void getRand(){ 
//Generates number between 0-3
        int x100 = 0;
        double randomNum = 0.0;
        randomNum = Math.random();
        x100 = (int) (randomNum * 100);
        randNSEW = x100 % 4;
    }

    public static void getRandSecundus(){ 
//Generates number between 0-2 for corrections
        int x100 = 0;
        double randomNum = 0.0;
        randomNum = Math.random();
        x100 = (int) (randomNum * 100);
        randNSEWS = x100 % 3;
    }

    public int getNextRow(){
        return nextrow;
    }

    public int getNextCol(){
        return nextcol;
    }

    enum Mode {WALKING, CORRECTING};
    Mode mode =  Mode.WALKING;

    public boolean processing(){
    for(int i = 1; i < 26; i ++){ //Goes until it hits Z

        if (mode == Mode.WALKING) {
            getRand(); //Retrieves random direction
            if(randNSEW == 0){
                nextcol--; //west
            }
            if(randNSEW == 1){
                nextrow++; //south
            }
            if(randNSEW == 2){
                nextcol++; //east
            }
            if(randNSEW == 3){
                nextrow--; //north
            }
        }

//if walker goes out of bounds they are arrested.
        if(nextrow < 0 || nextrow >= 10 || nextcol < 0 || nextcol >= 10) {
            return false;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 0 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
            //If walker headed west and lands somewhere it has already been
            i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
            nextcol++; //Moves back in to place.
            mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
            getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
            if(randNSEWS == 0){
                nextrow++; //Check South.
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 1){
                nextcol++; //Check East.
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 2){
                nextrow--; //Check North.
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 1 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
            //If walker headed south and lands somewhere it has already been
            i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
            nextrow--; //Moves back in to place.
            mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
            getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
            if(randNSEWS == 0){
                nextcol--; //Check West
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 1){
                nextcol++; //Check East
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 2){
                nextrow--; //Check North
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 2 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
            //If walker headed east and lands somewhere it has already been
            i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
            nextcol--; //Moves back in to place.
            mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
            getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
            if(randNSEWS == 0){
                nextcol--; //Check West
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 1){
                nextrow++; //Check South
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 2){
                nextrow--; //Check North
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 3 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
            //If walker headed north and lands somewhere it has already been
            i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
            nextrow++; //Moves back in to place.
            mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
            getRandSecundus();
            if(randNSEWS == 0){
                nextcol--; //Check West
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 1){
                nextrow++; //Check South
            }
            if(randNSEWS == 2){
                nextcol++; //Check East
            }
            continue;
        }

        mode = Mode.WALKING;
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    return true;
}




    public char[][] DisplayGrid() {
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.print(walkgrid[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return walkgrid;
}
}

public class WalkTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inpr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inpc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inpchoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        char choice = 'y';

        while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("Please enter x coordinate between 1 and 10.");
            r = inpr.nextInt();
            r = r - 1;

            System.out.println("Please enter y coordinate between 1 and 10");
            c = inpr.nextInt();
            c = c - 1;

            if(r < 0 || r > 9 || c < 0 || c > 9){
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
                if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                    continue;
                }
                else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                    choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
                }
            }
            DrunkWalker drunkwalker = new DrunkWalker(r, c);
            boolean walkerSucceeded = drunkwalker.processing();
            drunkwalker.DisplayGrid();
            if(walkerSucceeded) {
            System.out.println("You made it home");
            } else {
            System.out.println("You were arrested");
            }

            System.out.println("Restart? y/n");
            choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                continue;
            }
            else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you ve been parading this program for long - do you ever give points to the people who helped you??

Comment: Yes, I just don't have enough rep yet so it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In your process of finding a new direction to travel, you never set `randNSEW` to accommodate the change. You need to add a line that re-assigns it to correspond to the direction associated with the new `randNSEWS` value. Working code below:

```
if(randNSEW == 0 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
    //If walker headed west and lands somewhere it has already been
    i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
    nextcol++; //Moves back in to place.
    mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
    getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
    if(randNSEWS == 0){
        nextrow++; //Check South.
        randNSEW = 1; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 1){
        nextcol++; //Check East.
        randNSEW = 2; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 2){
        nextrow--; //Check North.
        randNSEW = 3; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    continue;
}
if(randNSEW == 1 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
    //If walker headed south and lands somewhere it has already been
    i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
    nextrow--; //Moves back in to place.
    mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
    getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
    if(randNSEWS == 0){
        nextcol--; //Check West
        randNSEW = 0; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 1){
        nextcol++; //Check East
        randNSEW = 2; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 2){
        nextrow--; //Check North
        randNSEW = 3; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    continue;
}
if(randNSEW == 2 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
    //If walker headed east and lands somewhere it has already been
    i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
    nextcol--; //Moves back in to place.
    mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
    getRandSecundus(); //Calls for secondary random number.
    if(randNSEWS == 0){
        nextcol--; //Check West
        randNSEW = 0; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 1){
        nextrow++; //Check South
        randNSEW = 1; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 2){
        nextrow--; //Check North
        randNSEW = 3; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    continue;
}
if(randNSEW == 3 && walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] != '.'){
    //If walker headed north and lands somewhere it has already been
    i--; //Sets the counter back so it won't go further than Z.
    nextrow++; //Moves back in to place.
    mode = Mode.CORRECTING;
    getRandSecundus();
    if(randNSEWS == 0){
        nextcol--; //Check West
        randNSEW = 0; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 1){
        nextrow++; //Check South
        randNSEW = 1; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    if(randNSEWS == 2){
        nextcol++; //Check East
        randNSEW = 2; /////////////////////////// THIS LINE ADDED
    }
    continue;
}
```

Also, an oversight:  There is no check to see if all four adjacent locations have already been used. If the `DrunkWalker` moves to a location that is surrounded by locations it has already visited, the program will hang, as it cannot find another direction to travel in. I would suggest writing in another `if` statement that checks to see if the `DrunkWalker` is trapped, and arrest him if so.

Comment: I need to figure out how to make sure if it goes out of bounds, it will return to position like how it does if it meets somewhere it has already been. I keep trying different ways and the logic seems air-tight but for some reason it just won't work. I reverted my project back to how it was before I tried this.

http://pastebin.com/ne1YC65n

What is the best way to do this?